# Pass Telerik date picker value to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a standard edit form generated when creating a controller index/Edit/Create/Delete views. One of the fields is a date so I have added a demo of Telerik (mainly to have a play) and would like to use the date picker for that field.

The original code is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InstallDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InstallDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InstallDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Which I have changed to:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InstallDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
              .Name("datepicker")
              .Value(Model.InstallDate)
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:150px" })
                )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InstallDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

The date picker renders file however I can't figure out how to pass the value picked back to the controller so it saves it.

How save the date picker value?

Answer (score 0):

Carried on researching and found that I am using the wrong function call. Instead of using  @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker() all I actually needed to do was change:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.InstallDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

for

```
@Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor( model => model.InstallDate)
```